# CORS not working correctly with Fastify: "Failed to fetch. CORS Network Failure URL"

Tags: cors, swagger-ui, fastify

I have an application built with **fastify** and are failing with CORS.

I have installed the plugin `fastify-cors` and configured as follows:

### Code

```
import fastify from 'fastify'
import cors from '@fastify/cors'

const server = fastify({
  logger: pino({ level: 'info' }),
})

await server.register(cors, { 
    origin: '*',
    methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS'],
    allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization', 'Origin', 'X-Requested-With', 'Accept'],
  })
```

Nevertheless, it does not work. Although I can see the CORS settings via curl in the response of any API call, browsers will fail.

```
❯ curl -vX 'GET' \
  'http://localhost:5000/api/1/2/test' \
  -H 'accept: application/json'
```

### Response:

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< access-control-allow-origin: *
< vary: Origin
< content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< content-length: 3
< Date: Sun, 26 Mar 2023 21:46:59 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< Keep-Alive: timeout=72
```

### Swagger

Using Swagger in Chrome-Browser shows an error:

> Failed to fetch. Possible Reasons:
>
> CORS Network Failure URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS
> request.

Unfortunately, Chrome Network Console does not show any requests made by Swagger-UI. So  I can't debug on this level.

What could be the cause of CORS not working?

[image]

Comment: Show the client code. You most likely tried something like `fetch('localhost:5000/api/1/2/test')` and forgot to specify the scheme of the URL.

Comment: 1) What's the error message in the Console tab in Chrome dev tools? 2) Is Swagger UI also running at `localhost:5000` or on another port?

Comment: In CORS registeration don't assing array to method, instead try the following way, ` server.register(cors, {
    origin: '*',
    methods: 'OPTION, GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
    preflightContinue: false,
    optionsSuccessStatus: 204,
    exposedHeaders: 'Authorization'
  });`

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error. In my case, the error occurred because I specified a host without a port in the Swagger options. Therefore, the host on which Fastify was run did not match the host that was specified in the Swagger options. If the reason for your error is the same, then the problem can be solved in two ways:

1. in the Swagger options, specify a host with the same port that Fastify is listening on.
2. remove host from Swagger options. As the [documentation](https://swagger.io/specification/v2) says,

> If the host is not included, the host serving the documentation is to
> be used (including the port).